# Problem with installation of language

Tags: software-installation

I wanted the system language to be in Korean. When I went to Language Support and loaded korean, I had got the next message:

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package fonts-nanum.

(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 230075 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fonts-nanum (from .../fonts-nanum_3.020-1ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-gnome-ko-base.
Unpacking language-pack-gnome-ko-base (from .../language-pack-gnome-ko-base_1%%3a12.10+20121009_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-ko-base.
Unpacking language-pack-ko-base (from .../language-pack-ko-base_1%%3a12.10+20121009_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-ko.
Unpacking language-pack-ko (from .../language-pack-ko_1%%3a12.10+20121009_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-gnome-ko.
Unpacking language-pack-gnome-ko (from .../language-pack-gnome-ko_1%%3a12.10+20121009_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kde-l10n-ko.
Unpacking kde-l10n-ko (from .../kde-l10n-ko_4%%3a4.9.5-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-kde-ko.
Unpacking language-pack-kde-ko (from .../language-pack-kde-ko_1%%3a12.10+20121005.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package firefox-locale-ko.
Unpacking firefox-locale-ko (from .../firefox-locale-ko_19.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-nanum-coding.
Unpacking fonts-nanum-coding (from .../fonts-nanum-coding_2.0-4ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-unfonts-core.
Unpacking fonts-unfonts-core (from .../fonts-unfonts-core_1.0.3.is.1.0.2-080608-5ubuntu2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hunspell-ko.
Unpacking hunspell-ko (from .../hunspell-ko_0.5.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ibus-hangul.
Unpacking ibus-hangul (from .../ibus-hangul_1.4.1-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice-l10n-ko.
Unpacking libreoffice-l10n-ko (from .../libreoffice-l10n-ko_1%%3a3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice-help-ko.
Unpacking libreoffice-help-ko (from .../libreoffice-help-ko_1%%3a3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package thunderbird-locale-ko.
Unpacking thunderbird-locale-ko (from .../thunderbird-locale-ko_1%%3a17.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig ...
Processing triggers for software-center ...
INFO:softwarecenter.db.update:translation information in database is up-to-date
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up postgresql-common (129ubuntu1) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server        
[ OK ]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server         * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-03-11 23:54:20 GMT FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main" has group or world access
2013-03-11 23:54:20 GMT DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).

[fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up fonts-nanum (3.020-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up kde-l10n-ko (4:4.9.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up firefox-locale-ko (19.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1) ...
Setting up fonts-nanum-coding (2.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fonts-unfonts-core (1.0.3.is.1.0.2-080608-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up hunspell-ko (0.5.5-1) ...
Setting up ibus-hangul (1.4.1-1) ...
Setting up libreoffice-l10n-ko (1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libreoffice-help-ko (1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-ko (1:17.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1) ...
Setting up language-pack-ko (1:12.10+20121009) ...
Setting up language-pack-ko-base (1:12.10+20121009) ...
Generating locales...
  ko_KR.UTF-8... hash collision (1701936715) ko_KR.utf8, es_CO.utf8
failed
Generation complete.
Setting up language-pack-gnome-ko (1:12.10+20121009) ...
Setting up language-pack-kde-ko (1:12.10+20121005.1) ...
Setting up language-pack-gnome-ko-base (1:12.10+20121009) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
Error in function: 
Setting up postgresql-common (129ubuntu1) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server        
[ OK ]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server         * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-03-11 23:54:29 GMT FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main" has group or world access
2013-03-11 23:54:29 GMT DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).

[fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Don't paste unformatted text walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-03-11 23:54:20 GMT FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main" has group or world access
2013-03-11 23:54:20 GMT DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
```

The log says the file /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main has wrong permission, it should be 0700. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then run:

```
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
```

Then fix all broken/half-installed packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install language-pack-ko` in a Terminal window. If that doesn't work, either paste the output here *in a code block* (do not just paste unformatted text into your question, as that's pretty unreadable) or link to an online paste from something like pastebin.